# Strange conflicting value when using tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string in tensorflow 1.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

The python code is simple as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse


if __name__ == '__main__':
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('--train')
   args = parser.parse_args()

   tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
           "traindata",
           'train_data.hdf5',
           'train data'
           )
   print('args: ', args.train)
   print('FLAG: ', tf.app.flags.FLAGS.traindata)
```

However, the output is strange:

```
$ python test.py --train 123
args:  123
FLAG:  123
```

As long as the `tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string` defined string name's prefix is equal to the string of `args` argument name, the `tf.app.flags.FLAGS` string value is exactly the same as the `args` argument value. That means `tf.app.flags.FLAGS` definition is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `tf.flags` is just a simple wrapper around `argparse`, this is the feature of `argparse` that allows you prefix match the argument. Python 3.5 and later ones allow you disable this feature by:

`parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(..., allow_abbrev=False)`